# Arrange Data as per Spreadsheet 1 in spreadsheet 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 spreadsheets and want to arrange the data in spreadsheet 2 as per the spreadsheet 1.
The standard format of the data is in spreadsheet 1. The data in spreadsheet 2 is not in a standard format.
The data is large and the manual work takes time to arrange the columns.
I'm sharing the screenshots as an example for reference.

Spreadsheet 1 (Standard Format)

[image]

Spreadsheet 2

[image]

P.S.: Can it be arranged as per the spreadsheet 1 or as per the headings ( here, headings are A,B,C.....)

Your help is much appreciated and thank you in advance.

Happy New Year to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a formula `SORT` that is made especially for this:

```
=SORT(A1:I6,1,1,TRUE)
```

You may also need to use `FILTER` if you have a different number of rows each time:

```
=SORT(FILTER(A:I,A:A<>""),1,1,TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can swap the column by programmatic. The [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) can do it.

##### Install exceljs

```
npm install exceljs
```

##### Prepare Excel Data.xls

[image]

#### Save 'swap.js' file

```js
const Excel = require('exceljs');

async function swapColumns(filePath, inputSheetName, outputSheetName, columnPairs) {
    // Create a new workbook and read the file
    let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    await workbook.xlsx.readFile(filePath);

    // Access the input worksheet
    let inputWorksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(inputSheetName);

    // Create or access the output worksheet
    let outputWorksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(outputSheetName) || workbook.addWorksheet(outputSheetName);

    // Create a temporary storage for the column data
    let tempColumns = {};

    // Initialize temporary storage with data from the input worksheet
    inputWorksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, (row, rowNumber) => {
        row.eachCell({ includeEmpty: true }, (cell, colNumber) => {
            if (!tempColumns[colNumber]) {
                tempColumns[colNumber] = [];
            }
            tempColumns[colNumber][rowNumber] = cell.value;
        });
    });

    // Perform the column swaps in the temporary storage
    columnPairs.forEach(([col1, col2]) => {
        [tempColumns[col1], tempColumns[col2]] = [tempColumns[col2], tempColumns[col1]];
    });

    // Write the data from the temporary storage to the output worksheet
    Object.keys(tempColumns).forEach(colNumber => {
        tempColumns[colNumber].forEach((value, rowNumber) => {
            if (rowNumber > 0) { // Skip undefined rowNumber 0
                outputWorksheet.getRow(rowNumber).getCell(parseInt(colNumber)).value = value;
            }
        });
    });

    // Write the changes to the file
    await workbook.xlsx.writeFile(filePath);
    console.log('Columns swapped and written to new sheet successfully');
}

// Usage
const filePath = 'Data.xlsx';
const inputSheetName = 'Sheet1';
const outputSheetName = 'Sheet2';
const columnPairs = [
    [3, 4], // Swap columns C and D
    [5, 6], // Swap columns E and F
    [6, 7]  // Swap columns F and G
];

swapColumns(filePath, inputSheetName, outputSheetName, columnPairs)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

##### Run it

```bash
node swap.js
```

[image]

##### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any formula which can be used in this scenario to run in the same sheet ?

Comment: It is a manual job, copy column C to paste content only to the empty column. copy column D to another empty column too, then replace Column C by Column D then column D replace from column C content. if your columns contain a lot of data, this could be a time-consuming process. For large datasets or frequent operations, a programmatic approach (like using ExcelJS) is more efficient.

Comment: For large data set, Do we need to enter the details manually .                                                               "// Usage
const filePath = 'Data.xlsx';
const inputSheetName = 'Sheet1';
const outputSheetName = 'Sheet2';
const columnPairs = [
    [3, 4], // Swap columns C and D
    [5, 6], // Swap columns E and F
    [6, 7]  // Swap columns F and G
];"

Comment: Yes, there are filename, input sheet, output sheet, and pair of swap. example [3,4] means swap column C and column D. It is not necessary how much size of rows. It will take over by swapColumns function.